# Limitations on amount of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

What are the limitations in terms of performance of MySQL when it comes to the amount of rows in a table? I currently have a running project that runs cronjobs every hour. Those gather data and write them into the database.

In order to boost the performance, I'm thinking about saving the data of those cronjobs in a table. (Not just the result, but all the things). The data itself will be something similar to this;

```
imgId (INT,FKEY->images.id) | imgId (INT,FKEY->images.id) | myData(INT)
```

So, the actual data per row is quite small. The problem is, that the amount of rows in this table will grow exponentially. With every imgId I add, I need the `myData` for **every** other image. That means, with 3000 images, I will have 3000^2 = 9 million rows (not counting the diagonals because I'm too lazy to do it now).

I'm concered about what MySQL can handle with such preconditions. Every hour will add roughly 100-300 new entries in the origin-table, meaning 10,000 to 90,000 new entries in the cross table.

Several questions arise:

- Are there limitations to the number of rows in a table?
- When (if) will MySQL significally drop performance?
- What actions can I take to make this cross-table as fast (acessible-wise, writing doesn't have to be fast) as possible?

**EDIT**

I just finished by polynomial interpolation and it turns out the growth will not be as drastic as I originally thought. As the relation `1-2` has the same data as `2-1`, I only need "half" a table, bringing the growth down to `(x^2-x)/2`.

Still, it will get a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9 million rows is not a huge table. Given the structure you provided, as long as it's indexed properly performance of select / update / insert queries won't be an issue. DDL may be a bit slow.

Since all the rows are already described by a cartesian join, you don't need to populate the entire table.

If the order of the image pairs is not significant then you can save some space by sorting the attributes or using a two / three table schema where the imgIds are equivalent.

Comment: Well, then when does a table get huge? Billions? I hope the project will run quite some time, so it actually is in the range of possibility